# Range of columns from table based on user input

Tags: r

I have a table with columns ranging from foo1...... foo999 . Could you give me a code in R to extract a set number of columns as needed by the user. The user should be able to decide about what range of columns he needs i.e from 1 to 60 in a separate table or maybe its 1 to 565 that the user needs. I tried a couple of methods. This is what I have currently. The solution seems to be quite basic but I can't find it anywhere.

```
number <- readline(prompt="Enter the number of columns: ")
subset(data, select=foo1:foo(number))
```

The expected output is the contents of the columns from the range that the user needs preferably stored in another variable so that I could use the data for further analysis.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [how to give reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a construct that could do it:

```
number <- readline(prompt="Enter the number of columns: ")
columns<- eval(parse(text=number))

df_selected <- df[,columns]
```

This will handle the user entering something like `3:8` or `c(1,4,9)`, etc.